# How can I color all layers below without coloring over transparent background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a logo consisting of a group of paths and smart objects, so I want them to stay editable.

#### Layers:

[image: layers]

Now all these are white in color. Behind them is transparency. I want to color all the layers at once, while keeping them editable.

1. I tried blending modes with layers above them, but all results either did not color or left the background colored as well.
2. I tried an adjustment layer but it just didn't do anything.

#### Blending mode example:

[image: blending mode example]

I need the logo itself to say, for this example, blue, but the background transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group all the layers containing the elements you wish to color.

Highlight the Group in the Layers Panel.

Choose Layer > Layer Style > Color Overlay and pick your color.